# Migrations in FastAPI libs?

Tags: django, fastapi

In Django it is quite convenient that 3d party libs could store their own models and migrations. F.e. django-celery-beat - it has functionality which require database table. It is also convenient to have single settings object from which 3d party libs could get necessary settings.

But what about FastAPI? How 3d party lib could say a user which settings it needs? How to provide a user functionality which requires a database table?

Comment: FastAPI doesn't have a built-in database layer, so there is no need for migrations. So any migration support would depend on which library you're using for database access - SQLAlchemy (and thus SQLModel) is usually paired with Alembic for migrations (by the same author as SQLAlchemy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if you create your lib that needs any table in database, you may create it with dependencies, it can contain dependencies as an alembic, for example
and user may install this lib and after this user has to run in console like
`your-lib start -d <database_url>`, I hope you understand my point